# What are the benefits and issues of using assigning parameters vs Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ecmascript-6

Given the 3 options below of creating a new object. Could someone explain to me what works best? Pros and cons? any issues regarding 'security' etc? I am hoping for a depth technical answer. I understand the output, But I don't understand the technical implications implementing on secure enterprise application.

This is purely used to construct/deconstruct an object with properties to pass/receive over to server as JSON.

Method 1

```
class Obj{

 constructor(private a: String, private b: Number){}

}
```

Method 2

```
class Obj {
 private _a: String;
 private _b: Number;

 get a() {
   return this._a;
 }

 set a(val: String) {
   this._a = val;
 }

 get b() {
   return this._b;
 }

 set b(b: Number) {
   this._b = b;
 }

 constructor(private a: String, private b: Number){
       this._a = a;
       this._b = b;
 }

}
```

Method 3

```
class Obj {
 private a: String;
 private b: Number;

 constructor(obj){

  Object.assign(this, obj)

 }
}
```

Comment: You're using the second one incorrectly, getters and setters should be set, when you want a variable return something dynamically.

Comment: Oops! fixed it :)

Comment: Are you always going to have two properties, or possibly more?

Comment: @torazaburo more... I am aware of the implication when you have alot of properties which means its a pain to manage. I am hoping there more to it than that.

Comment: The second one is simply logically incorrect. Again, youbuse getters and setter when you don't want to straight return something or set something. For example, you can use a custom setter, when you want a variable to be between certain bounds.

Comment: @Bálint actually not. It's a good practice to use getters and setters even if it returns something static. Because you lay the foundation for literacy code in advance.

Comment: @GProst [It's not](https://nemisj.com/why-getterssetters-is-a-bad-idea-in-javascript/)

Comment: @Bálint use [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) of TypeScript to deal with those problems

Comment: What about between 1 and 3?